# Java Object and toString() property and create 2 different outcomes

Tags: java, object

I have 2 objects:

1. `ObjectA`
2. `ObjectB`

When I turn ObjectA to a string (ObjectA.toString()) it looks like this:

```
projectA.test.Object@e6db18d
```

Now with ObjectB when I turn it to a string (ObjectB.toString()) it looks like this:

```
ObjectB {color=StringProperty [value: blue], car=StringProperty [value: bmw]}
```

Now my question is why does one present a a string of numbers and letters while the other one presents me with a list? How can I do it that all my objects are presented like lists similar to ObjectB as this would be easier to read?

Comment: I believe ObjectB and ObjectA are not objected of the same class. Override toString in class of ObjectA

Comment: Because `ObjectA` class has not overriden toString method and `ObjectB` class have

Comment: Your problem is interesting but please provide a Example to reproduce the behaviour... ObjectB probably override toString to return something and ObjectA defaults to the implementation

Comment: It was a question given to me by a friend . Was wondering about it but yes, now that you mention it, I am sure that one had toString() overriden and presented it like in the example above. Thank you all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The string value of an object is obtained through the `toString()` method. Therefore, to change the string representation of an object, the `toString()` method must be overridden in the class:

```
public class SomeClass {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Custom string";
    }

}
```

The string representation of `ObjectA` is the default string representation of any object, where the name of the class of the object is printed, followed by `@`, and finally, the hash code of the object. The default implementation is:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```